# Installation of "Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Express Edition Service Pack 2 (KB 921896)" failed (0x80070643)

Tags: windows, windows-10, sql-server-2005

I already tried a lot to fix the following problem:
I try to install some Windows updates on a Windows 10 PC.

The update for "Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Express Edition Service Pack 2 (KB 921896)" breaks with error code 0x80070643. This version is needed for an old application.

I tried to install it manually but the installation of this files break too: http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/search.aspx?q=kb2463332
I also reinstalled NET Framework.

Did somebody face the same problem already and can give me some more hints to fix this?

Best regards´!

Comment: It's been EOL for 4 years. You'd probably do better putting it in a Win7 VM & not letting it anywhere near the outside world.

Comment: @Tetsujin: We're talking Vista here ...

Answer (score 0):

Error code 0x80070643 is meaningless: it stands for ERROR_INSTALL_FAILURE.
You could also try to disable the antivirus.

A user
[reported success](http://forums.techarena.in/windows-update/701955.htm#post3841610)
with this method:

> 1. Opened the SQL Server Configuration Manager
> 2. Opened SQL Server 2005 Network Coniguration
> 3. Right clicked on Protocols for MSSMLBIZ and selected Properties
> 4. Set Force Encryption to No
> 5. Opened SQL Server 2005 Services
> 6. Started SQL Server (MSSMLBIZ) and SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)
> 7. Installed KB 921896